# Move an existing Stack Exchange account to a new user account?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

I have recently signed in at a non-tech Stack Exchange while I have had only technical Stack Exchange accounts before. Now I would like to keep tech and non-tech separate. I would like to do the opposite of a merge of two user accounts. I will create a new user account, and then I would like to move that non-tech account to the new user account.

Is this possible?

Comment: No. You need to create a new login (different email address and not have them merged).

Comment: There is now a feature request at [Allow moving an existing Stack Exchange account to a new user account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359512/allow-moving-an-existing-stack-exchange-account-to-a-new-user-account).